# Setting a seed to shuffle ArrayList in Java deterministically

Tags: java, random

I have a list of integers (currently using [cern.colt.list.IntArrayList](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/list/IntArrayList.html)). I can call "shuffle()" and randomly shuffle them. I would like to be able to reproduce a shuffle. I can reproduce a series of random numbers by setting a seed. I do not seem to be able to set a seed in this case. What should I do? I am open to other implementations.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not seem to be able to set a seed in this case".  Did you write some code and not get the results you expected?  How about posting the code?

Comment: Possibly because it's old, the colt implementation does have a second shuffle implementation (where you can set a seed). Looks like I need to move away from it.

Comment: Meant to say the colt implementation does _not_ have a Random optional argument.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is possible by using the shuffle method that allows you to provide the backing `Random` instance: [`Collections.shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29):

Example:

```
Collections.shuffle(yourList, new Random(somePredefinedSeed));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the Random instance with a seed value using [public static void shuffle(List list,
                           Random rnd)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29). For the [Random(long seed)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) constructor you can specify a seed.

From Java Docs:

> Randomly permute the specified list
>   using the specified source of
>   randomness. All permutations occur
>   with equal likelihood assuming that
>   the source of randomness is fair.

Answer (score 3):

there is an [alternative method which takes a Random as source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)