# Default source of randomness in collections.shuffle

Tags: java, random, collections

In `collections.shuffle` we can specify Random seed as an argument which I was passing as System.namoTime() so as to ensure that the randomization is different each time.

I wanted to know what is the default source of Randomness for this api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Setting a seed to shuffle ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284589/setting-a-seed-to-shuffle-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a new [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) when you call `shuffle` method (if there is no previous `Random` assigned to `static` `r`):

```
private static Random r;

public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {

         if (r == null) {
             r = new Random();
         }
         shuffle(list, r);
     }
```

You can pry into the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java).